# Major Headache Creating Folders & Subfolders in Google script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Help me someone pleaassee..

I'm ok with working with google sheet scripts but this one has got me so frustrated I can't find the answer I am looking for anywhere. (Its so simple saying it out loud but my god its much more hard work getting it to be done as a script!)

I am trying to (and failing !) to create a google sheet script that will create a folder and Subfolders and within the subfolders more folders.

I really don't have much code for this, I did copy and paste a few pages worth of code but it kept getting more and more complex.

All I need is 
Main Folder would be name of project ?
Column A is the Departments (Sub Folder)
Column B , C , D (Sub Folder to heading to Column A)

The link to my sheet is here

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eJ03EC7pfxGfin5unO-aMPDE92jlvYCW-0zbnlwxHPU/edit?usp=sharing

The sheet may look small but it would have over 100 depts in total and I don't really want to be creating them every month one by one.

Any help would be really appreciated, or someone to point me in the right direction (please don't say Google it!)

So To all the google guru's PLEASE HELP ME... (you never know you may also be helping others too :)

Kind Humble Regards

A Failing Coder!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Generally, when asking a question we like to see some attempt at code through the asker providing a [mcve] as this is not a coding service. What have you found/tried so far? Did you get errors?

Comment: Hi Chris, Sorry I was not trying someone to do the code for me I just wanted some sort of guidance as what ever I tried it would simply not work (can't share code I got fed-up and deleted the whole thing in frustration!) . I can fill in all the gaps with some guidance. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea here is to:

1. get values from your sheet
2. get your root folder
3. create sub- and subsubfolders in the root based on the sheet values

Here's more or less how you go about it:

```
function createFolders() {
  // part 1: getting the values
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('YOUR-SHEET');
  var values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  // part 2: getting the root folder
  var rootFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('YOUR-FOLDER-ID');

  // part 3: iterate through values to create folders
  for (var i in values) {
    // you can call DriveApp's createFolder function on another folder
    // thus the new one will be created inside the folder you're calling the function on
    var folder = rootFolder.createFolder(values[i][0]);
    folder.createFolder(values[i][3]);
  } 
}
```

Comment: // part 2: getting the root folder
  var rootFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('YOUR-FOLDER-ID'); Can this be done without using getFolderbyId option ?

Comment: yes, check the docs: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#createfoldername — you can just call it on `DriveApp`, then your folder is going to be created in the root of your drive